# Build Ubuntu 5.15 kernel with mgLRU patches

Tags: kernel, patch

mgLRU patches can give a lot of advantages for my workload but 6.1 kernel is not compatible with some soft I have to use. So I want to stay with current Ubuntu 5.15 LTS kernel, but have to build kernel manually with additional patches.

mgLRU v5 patch can be applied to 5.15 kernel without any changes, but newer v15 (https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20220918080010.2920238-1-yuzhao@google.com/T/) can not.

Should I use old v5 version or is there any ported v15 version to 5.15 kernel? I was not able to find any in google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel free to cherry pick from our [repo](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromiumos/third_party/kernel/+/3948112/2). (You need to sign in first and then click the three dots at the top right corner.)